# Al copiar de un txt a otro, el final de la línea no se copia. Puede que porque lleva : o espacio

Tags: batch

Seguro que es un detalle que se me escapa, pero estoy intentado copiar ciertas líneas de un txt a otro txt utlizando:

`for /F %%i in (fichero1.txt) do @echo %%i >> fichero2.txt`

El problema está en que las líneas del fichero1 tiene en su contenido dos puntos ":", por ejemplo:

```
"checkoutparent": "1.28.4",
"checkoutparent": "1.28.3",
"checkoutparent": "1.28.2",
```

Y lo que se copia en el fichero2 es:

```
"checkoutparent": 
"checkoutparent": 
"checkoutparent":
```

No sé el motivo por el que no se copia la versión. No sé si es el espacio en blanco o qué puede ser. He intentado borrar el espacio en blanco pero nada. Lo he intentado así:

```
Echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F %%i in (fichero1.txt) do (
echo.
set %%i=%i: =%
echo %%i
)
```

Comment: Quieres copiar la línea entera?

Comment: No edites tu pregunta añadiendo SOLUCIONADO al título. Si la respuesta recibida es válida, basta con aceptarla, así la comunidad entiende que es una respuesta que soluciona el problema. Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El comando [`for /f`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) actúa sobre las líneas del archivo, dividiendolas en *tokens*. Por defecto solo usa el primer token y. los delimitadores son: el espacio, la coma, el igual y el punto y coma.

Tanto los delimitadores como los tokens que quieres utilizar se pueden configurar. Entre la `/f` y tu variable (`%%i` en este caso) colocas las opciones entre comillas.

Las opciones de interés son:

- `delims=...` para configurar los delimitadores.
- `tokens=n` para configurar los tokens que quieres usar.

Por ejemplo, con `"delims="` haces que toda el token sea la línea completa. Tal vez sea esto lo que necesitas.

O si quisieras dividir una línea con la siguiente forma:

```
"checkoutparent": "1.28.4",
```

En `"checkoutparent":` y `"1.28.4",` el comando sería el siguiente:

```
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims= " %%i %%j un (fichero) do echo %%i %%j
```

Comment: Me funcionó perfectamente. Muchas gracias!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Es importante saber que cuando usas el comando /F, los espacios en blanco funcionan como delimitadores. Si revisas tu archivo fuente en este caso tienes ":" y espacio.

```
"checkoutparent": "1.28.4",
"checkoutparent": "1.28.3",
"checkoutparent": "1.28.2",
```

Al usar el comando `/F` deberías agregar la opción `"delims="` significa no analizar en tokens (para conservar cada línea completa) y además cada línea se cargaría iterativamente en la variable `%%i`. Por cierto, debes usar `"@echo off"` para eliminar cualquier mensaje previo, ya que veo usas Echo off.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "tokens=* delims=" %%i in (fichero1.txt) do (
    set "line=%%i"
    echo !line! >> fichero2.txt
)
```

Comment: Gracias contestar. Con la respuesta de Mateo lo solucioné.